# When make pop to NavigationController, Parent view controller hide

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

The settings that I have is:

`UINavigationController` -> `RootParentViewController`

Then `ParentViewController` have a `UIContainerView`. There I load dynamically content (Other's `UIViewController` Child).

When I make a transition from:

`UINavigationController` -> `RootParentViewController` (`ChildViewController`) -> Another `ChildViewController`

Using (it's working):

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subCategoryViewController,   animated: true)
```

I created my custom Back button (reason of design), But when I call:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

It's popping to the `ChildViewController` although is calling the `viewDidAppear` of `RootParentViewController` (is like hide the parent)

Answer (score 0):

I got it,

The problem is, that I was setting navigationBarHidden in the childViewController. Then when I made pop, navigation continue hidden.